# Parsing a nested json using gson

Tags: java, json, gson

What I am trying to do is to parse nested json data into a Java object using Gson and print it out with customized toString().

**The Json Content**

```
{"data": [
    {
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "circulating_supply": 18975050,
        "last_updated": "2022-03-05T13:54:00.000Z",
        "total_supply": 18975050,
        "cmc_rank": 1,
        "self_reported_circulating_supply": null,
        "platform": null,
        "tags": [
            "mineable",
            "pow",
            "sha-256",
            "store-of-value",
            "state-channel",
            "coinbase-ventures-portfolio",
            "three-arrows-capital-portfolio",
            "polychain-capital-portfolio",
            "binance-labs-portfolio",
            "blockchain-capital-portfolio",
            "boostvc-portfolio",
            "cms-holdings-portfolio",
            "dcg-portfolio",
            "dragonfly-capital-portfolio",
            "electric-capital-portfolio",
            "fabric-ventures-portfolio",
            "framework-ventures-portfolio",
            "galaxy-digital-portfolio",
            "huobi-capital-portfolio",
            "alameda-research-portfolio",
            "a16z-portfolio",
            "1confirmation-portfolio",
            "winklevoss-capital-portfolio",
            "usv-portfolio",
            "placeholder-ventures-portfolio",
            "pantera-capital-portfolio",
            "multicoin-capital-portfolio",
            "paradigm-portfolio"
        ],
        "date_added": "2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
        "quote": {"USD": {
            "fully_diluted_market_cap": 820131199762.62,
            "last_updated": "2022-03-05T13:54:00.000Z",
            "market_cap_dominance": 42.252,
            "percent_change_30d": 6.81621153,
            "percent_change_1h": -0.42008562,
            "percent_change_24h": -5.71623656,
            "market_cap": 741049072478.8419,
            "volume_change_24h": -11.0241,
            "price": 39053.8666553628,
            "percent_change_60d": -16.6843952,
            "volume_24h": 26123993408.855915,
            "percent_change_90d": -21.03603335,
            "percent_change_7d": -0.10097865
        }},
        "num_market_pairs": 9214,
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "max_supply": 21000000,
        "id": 1,
        "self_reported_market_cap": null,
        "slug": "bitcoin"
    },
    {
        "symbol": "ETH",
        "circulating_supply": 119834013.5615,
        "last_updated": "2022-03-05T13:54:00.000Z",
        "total_supply": 119834013.5615,
        "cmc_rank": 2,
        "self_reported_circulating_supply": null,
        "platform": null,
        "tags": [
            "mineable",
            "pow",
            "smart-contracts",
            "ethereum-ecosystem",
            "coinbase-ventures-portfolio",
            "three-arrows-capital-portfolio",
            "polychain-capital-portfolio",
            "binance-labs-portfolio",
            "blockchain-capital-portfolio",
            "boostvc-portfolio",
            "cms-holdings-portfolio",
            "dcg-portfolio",
            "dragonfly-capital-portfolio",
            "electric-capital-portfolio",
            "fabric-ventures-portfolio",
            "framework-ventures-portfolio",
            "hashkey-capital-portfolio",
            "kenetic-capital-portfolio",
            "huobi-capital-portfolio",
            "alameda-research-portfolio",
            "a16z-portfolio",
            "1confirmation-portfolio",
            "winklevoss-capital-portfolio",
            "usv-portfolio",
            "placeholder-ventures-portfolio",
            "pantera-capital-portfolio",
            "multicoin-capital-portfolio",
            "paradigm-portfolio",
            "injective-ecosystem",
            "bnb-chain"
        ],
        "date_added": "2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z",
        "quote": {"USD": {
            "fully_diluted_market_cap": 316405371023.81,
            "last_updated": "2022-03-05T13:54:00.000Z",
            "market_cap_dominance": 18.0363,
            "percent_change_30d": 1.39750424,
            "percent_change_1h": -0.82066438,
            "percent_change_24h": -3.20839994,
            "market_cap": 316405371023.81366,
            "volume_change_24h": -14.3764,
            "price": 2640.363629825611,
            "percent_change_60d": -31.31982292,
            "volume_24h": 12406258074.91051,
            "percent_change_90d": -37.45316954,
            "percent_change_7d": -4.71064229
        }},
        "num_market_pairs": 5543,
        "name": "Ethereum",
        "max_supply": null,
        "id": 1027,
        "self_reported_market_cap": null,
        "slug": "ethereum"
    },
 and so on...
]}
```

**POJO Classes : Example**

```
package controller;

import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<JsonFormatter> data = null;

    public List<JsonFormatter> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<JsonFormatter> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(Example.class.getName()).append('@').append(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))).append('[');
        sb.append("data");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.data == null)?"<null>":this.data));
        sb.append(',');
        if (sb.charAt((sb.length()- 1)) == ',') {
            sb.setCharAt((sb.length()- 1), ']');
        } else {
            sb.append(']');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

**POJO Classes : JsonFormatter**

```
package controller;


import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class JsonFormatter {

    @SerializedName("symbol")
    @Expose
    private String symbol;
    @SerializedName("circulating_supply")
    @Expose
    private Float circulatingSupply;
    @SerializedName("last_updated")
    @Expose
    private String lastUpdated;
    @SerializedName("total_supply")
    @Expose
    private Float totalSupply;
    @SerializedName("cmc_rank")
    @Expose
    private Float cmcRank;
    @SerializedName("self_reported_circulating_supply")
    @Expose
    private Object selfReportedCirculatingSupply;
    @SerializedName("platform")
    @Expose
    private Platform platform;
    @SerializedName("tags")
    @Expose
    private List<String> tags = null;
    @SerializedName("date_added")
    @Expose
    private String dateAdded;
    @SerializedName("quote")
    @Expose
    private Quote quote;
    @SerializedName("num_market_pairs")
    @Expose
    private Float numMarketPairs;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("max_supply")
    @Expose
    private Float maxSupply;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("self_reported_market_cap")
    @Expose
    private Object selfReportedMarketCap;
    @SerializedName("slug")
    @Expose
    private String slug;

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public Float getCirculatingSupply() {
        return circulatingSupply;
    }

    public void setCirculatingSupply(Float circulatingSupply) {
        this.circulatingSupply = circulatingSupply;
    }

    public String getLastUpdated() {
        return lastUpdated;
    }

    public void setLastUpdated(String lastUpdated) {
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }

    public Float getTotalSupply() {
        return totalSupply;
    }

    public void setTotalSupply(Float totalSupply) {
        this.totalSupply = totalSupply;
    }

    public Float getCmcRank() {
        return cmcRank;
    }

    public void setCmcRank(Float cmcRank) {
        this.cmcRank = cmcRank;
    }

    public Object getSelfReportedCirculatingSupply() {
        return selfReportedCirculatingSupply;
    }

    public void setSelfReportedCirculatingSupply(Object selfReportedCirculatingSupply) {
        this.selfReportedCirculatingSupply = selfReportedCirculatingSupply;
    }

    public Platform getPlatform() {
        return platform;
    }

    public void setPlatform(Platform platform) {
        this.platform = platform;
    }

    public List<String> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(List<String> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public String getDateAdded() {
        return dateAdded;
    }

    public void setDateAdded(String dateAdded) {
        this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
    }

    public Quote getQuote() {
        return quote;
    }

    public void setQuote(Quote quote) {
        this.quote = quote;
    }

    public Float getNumMarketPairs() {
        return numMarketPairs;
    }

    public void setNumMarketPairs(Float numMarketPairs) {
        this.numMarketPairs = numMarketPairs;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Float getMaxSupply() {
        return maxSupply;
    }

    public void setMaxSupply(Float maxSupply) {
        this.maxSupply = maxSupply;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Object getSelfReportedMarketCap() {
        return selfReportedMarketCap;
    }

    public void setSelfReportedMarketCap(Object selfReportedMarketCap) {
        this.selfReportedMarketCap = selfReportedMarketCap;
    }

    public String getSlug() {
        return slug;
    }

    public void setSlug(String slug) {
        this.slug = slug;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(JsonFormatter.class.getName()).append('@').append(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))).append('[');
        sb.append("symbol");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.symbol == null)?"<null>":this.symbol));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("circulatingSupply");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.circulatingSupply == null)?"<null>":this.circulatingSupply));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("lastUpdated");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.lastUpdated == null)?"<null>":this.lastUpdated));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("totalSupply");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.totalSupply == null)?"<null>":this.totalSupply));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("cmcRank");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.cmcRank == null)?"<null>":this.cmcRank));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("selfReportedCirculatingSupply");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.selfReportedCirculatingSupply == null)?"<null>":this.selfReportedCirculatingSupply));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("platform");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.platform == null)?"<null>":this.platform));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("tags");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.tags == null)?"<null>":this.tags));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("dateAdded");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.dateAdded == null)?"<null>":this.dateAdded));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("quote");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.quote == null)?"<null>":this.quote));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("numMarketPairs");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.numMarketPairs == null)?"<null>":this.numMarketPairs));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("name");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.name == null)?"<null>":this.name));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("maxSupply");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.maxSupply == null)?"<null>":this.maxSupply));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("id");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.id == null)?"<null>":this.id));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("selfReportedMarketCap");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.selfReportedMarketCap == null)?"<null>":this.selfReportedMarketCap));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("slug");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.slug == null)?"<null>":this.slug));
        sb.append(',');
        if (sb.charAt((sb.length()- 1)) == ',') {
            sb.setCharAt((sb.length()- 1), ']');
        } else {
            sb.append(']');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

There are also other classes for my POJO, and the way I tried to parse it into Gson is :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, ArrayList<JsonFormatter>>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, ArrayList<Example>> nodeProperties = gson.fromJson(json.toString(), type);
```

but when I try to print out its sub values like

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Example>> set : nodeProperties.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(set.getValue().get(0).getData().get(0).toString());
        }
```

I get the error :

```
class controller.JsonFormatter cannot be cast to class controller.Example (controller.JsonFormatter and controller.Example are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

What I want to achieve is to print the above json content as like this:

```
Symbol: BTC
Circulating_supply: 18975050
...
Tags:
    mineable
```

Can anyone please help me out to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in these lines:

```java
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, ArrayList<JsonFormatter>>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, ArrayList<Example>> nodeProperties = gson.fromJson(json.toString(), type);
```

The `TypeToken` is for `Map<String, ArrayList<JsonFormatter>>`, but you store the parsed JSON in a variable of type `Map<String, ArrayList<Example>>`. Unfortunately `Gson.fromJson(..., Type)` does not provide any type safety guarantees, therefore you must make sure that the provided `Type` matches the type of the variable you store the result in. Additionally due to Java's type erasure at runtime, you do not notice this `JsonFormatter` vs. `Example` mismatch until you iterate over the elements, causing the `ClassCastException`.

Based on the JSON data you provided, it looks to me like you could just use `gson.fromJson(json.toString(), Example.class)`, but please verify whether that is actually correct for your use case.

Comment: I modified toString() methods overrided in my POJO classes and did System.out.println(nodeProperties.toString()), but it took such a long time to change each of the toString() methods... Is it correct way to use it? or is there any simpler way?

Comment: @승기유, if you just want to transform the JSON data to your custom output format, but want to preserve all properties and don't want to change the representation of the property values, then you could probably use [`JsonReader`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html) to process the JSON data, and write the formatted output step by step to a `Writer` (or `StringBuilder`).

Comment: @승기유 Yeah, you seem to be misled by the answer in your previous question (and I have no a single idea why accepted despite even Jon Skeet didn't bother go get what you were trying to do that's kind of strange to me now) since it makes you use `toString` for what it was not designed for. As Marcono1234 says, you probably might need to use `JsonReader` to generate your output on fly, or simply don't use that bullshit POJO generator service and deserialize evreything you get into generic `JsonElement` that covers all possible JSON values without a line of POJO mapping.

Comment: @승기유 Also, if you don't use mappings in favor of JsonElement, you can easily walk it recursively and process any level of nesting, again not writing even a single line of mapping (that both takes time and may be just wrong). However, I don't think you're decomposing your problem right, sorry. Even if you can't do that, please ask your questions describing _what is your goal_, because answering your single questions with poor titles makes everybody here think you need exactly what you're asking no matter how far you're getting away from your goal.